# How effective is a phosphonate treatment for phytophthora dieback?

Tags: diseases, fungus

I found on the Internet that the fungal disease phytophthora dieback can be treated with phosphonates. I am asking how effective this treatment is. If it's not very effective, is there any other effective treatment?

Comment: Which plant and which variety of phytophthora - your use of the term 'dieback' might suggest an aerial form rather than trouble at the root, please clarify

Comment: Plants such as mango and custard apple.  Surely it is not due to drought. It might be a root root. And I am from south India.

Comment: It would be unusual for several different varieties of plant to all have phytophthera root rot - professional nurserymen or fruit growers might use phosphonates, either injected into trees at certain intervals, or applied to the soil, but its a specialist area - if you google 'phytophthora and phosphonates' there are a few scientific, PDF documents available which may or  may not be helpful - they're largely aimed at professional growers or are scientific research rather than info about dosage, timing and effectiveness for the amateur